# What is the easiest way to calculate how many days of same date between to days in postgresql

Tags: postgresql

To give an example, starting date '2016-01-01' and ending date '2016-06-01', the number of days of '10th' is 5 as it appears in every month from Jan to May. The number of days of '29th' is also 5 as it is a leap year. The number of days of '30th' is 4 and the number of days of '31st' is 3 as they only appear in certain months.

What is the easiest (or say most elegant) way to calculate this number given the starting and ending dates?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a list of dates using `generate_series()` and then count the occurrences of each day:

```
select extract(day from dt) as day_in_month, count(*)
from generate_series(date '2016-01-01', date '2016-06-01', interval '1' day) as g(dt)
group by extract(day from dt)
order by 1;
```

Comment: Cool, at least it works. Sorry cannot vote for you yet.